# React Native Apollo client always return the first fetch result in onComplete

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to do a pagination with `fetchMore` function which is provided by the client it self.

`const [getNewReleases, { loading, fetchMore,data:responseData }] = useLazyQuery(FIND_COMPANY)`


The first time the `getNewReleases` called with `page = 1` when user scroll to bottom, `fetchMore` is called with `page = 2`.

I handle the data using `onCompleted`, but the result is always the response of `page = 1` eventhough the request for `page = 2` is called ( I checked in the net work and I see the response)


This is the config in the cache

```
          keyArgs: false, 
          merge(existing = [], incoming) {
            let { result } = incoming 
            // return result || []
            if (result) {
              console.log('===== merged Data: ',[...result.data]);
              
              // return [...existing,...result.data]; this doesn't work
              return [...result.data] //this not work too
            }
            else return existing
          }
```

trying to do some log here, I can see that whenever fetchMore is called, it's run to this merger function twice, but return only the request with `page = 1`.

 Is there any fix for this?

Here's the response that I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM1fW.png